# NULL values appear when taking the sum of two columns taken from Lookup tables

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server and taking data from two lookup tables and want to take the sum of these two columns.

The problem arises when the sum of these two columns (lookup values) gives `NULL` values. However, I have used `COALESCE` to change the `NULL` values to zero.

The line I am calculating the sum is this one: `(t2.[Score]+t3.[Score]) as Total`

```
select  t1.[ID]
      ,t1.[District]
      ,[CLLG_Interventiond]
      ,t1.[UC_HH]
      ,t1.[Benef_Household]
      ,t1.[Duration_Years]
      ,t1.[Duration_Months]
      ,t1.[Budget_PKR]
      ,t1.[Priority]
      ,COALESCE(t2.[Score],0) as E_Score
      ,COALESCE(t3.[Score],0) as UCDP_Score
      ,(t2.[Score]+t3.[Score]) as Total
  FROM [dbo].[Data] as t1
  left outer join E_Growth as t2
  on t1.CLLG_Interventiond = t2.Intervention
  left outer join UCDP as t3
 on  t1.Priority = t3.Priority
```

Answer (score 13):

Try to use `COALESCE` for the values in the `SUM`
Like this:

```
COALESCE(t2.[Score],0) + COALESCE(t3.[Score],0) as Total
```

The query will look like this:

```
select  t1.[ID]
      ,t1.[District]
      ,[CLLG_Interventiond]
      ,t1.[UC_HH]
      ,t1.[Benef_Household]
      ,t1.[Duration_Years]
      ,t1.[Duration_Months]
      ,t1.[Budget_PKR]
      ,t1.[Priority]
      ,COALESCE(t2.[Score],0) as E_Score
      ,COALESCE(t3.[Score],0) as UCDP_Score
      ,COALESCE(t2.[Score],0) + COALESCE(t3.[Score],0) as Total
  FROM [dbo].[Data] as t1
  left outer join E_Growth as t2
  on t1.CLLG_Interventiond = t2.Intervention
  left outer join UCDP as t3
 on  t1.Priority = t3.Priority
```

Comment: My problem solved-Thank you very much for the support

Answer (score 7):

Since you already handled that, you can nest your query and calculate the total at the outer level:

```
SELECT T.*, T.E_SCORE + T.UCDP_SCORE AS total
FROM (
    select  t1.[ID]
           ,t1.[District]
           ,[CLLG_Interventiond]
           ,t1.[UC_HH]
           ,t1.[Benef_Household]
           ,t1.[Duration_Years]
           ,t1.[Duration_Months]
           ,t1.[Budget_PKR]
           ,t1.[Priority]
           ,COALESCE(t2.[Score],0) as E_Score
           ,COALESCE(t3.[Score],0) as UCDP_Score

   FROM [dbo].[Data] as t1
   left outer join E_Growth as t2
      on t1.CLLG_Interventiond = t2.Intervention
   left outer join UCDP as t3
      on  t1.Priority = t3.Priority
) as T
```

A CTE could have been used in the same way

Comment: My problem solved-Thank you very much for the support

Comment: Don't forget to mark this or one of the other answers as the correct answer. It will help feature readers to quickly find a solution if they have a similar påroblem. You do this by clicking on the check box at the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`CTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sqlhttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) with [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql):

> Returns one of two values, depending on whether the Boolean expression evaluates to true or false in SQL Server. e.g *IIF( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )*

```
WITH CTE AS
(
select  t1.[ID],
-- other columns...
,IIF(t2.[Score] IS NOT NULL, t2.[Score], 0) E_Score
,IIF(t3.[Score] IS NOT NULL, t3.[Score], 0) UCDP_Score
-- conditions of joining...
)
SELECT T.*, T.E_SCORE + T.UCDP_SCORE AS total FROM CTE as T;
```

Comment: Thanks - my problem solved